# Google Apps Script does not update Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I have a Google form that is filled and updated according to the values of a Google Sheets spreadsheet through an Apps Script code.
I put two triggers for the update, one when the person submits the form and another every minute. It turns out that, except for some cases of execution error, the triggers work without problems but the time triggers (every minute) do not always update the value.
They use old values that are no longer in the worksheet. And the funniest thing is that both triggers use the same code!

```
function atualizaDados(){
  // call your form and connect to the drop-down item
   var form = FormApp.openById("URL"); 
  var namesList = form.getItemById("2124567779").asListItem();
  var diaList = form.getItemById("1001915448").asListItem();
// identify the sheet where the data resides needed to populate the drop-down
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("URL"); //    getActive();
  var names = ss.getSheetByName("Prog Agenda");
  // grab the values in the first column of the sheet - use 2 to skip header row
  var quantidade = names.getRange("O10").getValue();
  var quantidadeDia = names.getRange("O12").getValue();
var DeuHora = names.getRange("B22").getValue();
  //Logger.log(quantidade);
  var namesValues = names.getRange(3, 12, quantidade).getValues();
  //var namesValues = names.getRange(3, 12, names.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  //var namesValues = names.getRange(3, 12, 12).getValues();
  //var diasValor = names.getRange(3, 14, names.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  var diasValor = names.getRange(3, 14, quantidadeDia).getValues();
  var studentNames = [];
  var diasDispo = [];
  // convert the array ignoring empty cells
  for(var i = 0; i < namesValues.length; i++){   
    if(namesValues[i][0] != ""){
      studentNames[i] = namesValues[i][0];
      Logger.log(studentNames);
    }
  }
//Logger.log(studentNames.values());
  // populate the drop-down with the array data
  namesList.setChoiceValues(studentNames);
  for(var i = 0; i < diasValor.length; i++){   
    if(diasValor[i][0] != ""){
      diasDispo[i] = diasValor[i][0];
Logger.log(diasDispo);
Logger.log(quantidade);
Logger.log(quantidadeDia);
Logger.log(DeuHora);
    }
  }
  // populate the drop-down with the array data
  diaList.setChoiceValues(diasDispo);
}
```

I even tested a different code to do this and the same thing happens, the timed trigger keeps putting the same old value. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: what is showing in the logs?

Comment: @BlindSpots I posted 3 images showing the spreadsheet, the log and the form.
[log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkrLn.png) [sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzL7q.png) [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5iob.png)

Comment: Thank you, please edit your question to include all relevant info, rather than putting it in comments.  Be sure to include and label sepperate log output from the success and the  failure, and describe how they  differ if not immediately obvious.  It is preferable to paste the actual text into a code block as opposed to taking screenshots. If the logs are identical, add additional logging to isolate the step(s) that are failing prior to posting the logs.

Comment: @BlindSpots In sheet, the values are dynamic, like appears the gym classes hours 12 hours before, and disappears 10 min before the class. In the example, in sheets appears the hours 6h00, 7h00 and 20h00, and an option to cancel my spot and reset the system but the 20h class must not appear, because pass the hour!
When a client submit an answer, the update works, but the timed trigger stay putting the same answers in form.

Comment: @BlindSpots I tried to put all this in the question but the system didn´t let me!
I will try edit!

Comment: I understand, FYI Stack Overflow is English only so you may need to do some translating of log text prior to posting. This is required but will also help make it easier to get an answer.